# Object's Enumerable property still showing in console after setting to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, console.log

Consider the following code

```
    let cat={name:'foo',color:'white'};
    Object.defineProperty(cat,'color',{enumerable:false})
    console.log(cat);
    Object.defineProperty(cat,'color',{enumerable:true})
    console.log(cat);
```

If I paste this code in chrome console, it still shows the `color` property in both log statements, but I run this in nodejs it show only in bottom log statement, what can possibly the cause of this behavior?

Here are the screenshots of NodeJS console output

[image: NodeJS output]

And here is the screenshot of chrome console

[image: Chrome Output]

Comment: This is console implementation specific. If you manually iterate enumarable properties to log them you'll get consistent output. see: [Console: Spot enumerable and non-enumerable properties](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#enumerable-properties), Chrome specifically logs all properties for debugging purposes, but highlights them differently.

Comment: "*what can possibly the cause of this behavior?*" there is no specification for consoles. They show you what they show you.

Comment: That's a poor dupe target, this has nothing to do with lazy evaluation.

Comment: The `enumerable` config parameter is just a flag for changing the behavior of an iterating context, not for hiding a object key.